# Creating a list that is iterable

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a list that is iterable and I'm stuck in the iterator part

this is my code

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class MappableList<T> implements Iterable<T> {

T list[];

public MappableList(T arg1, T arg2, T arg3, T arg4) {
    list = (T[]) new Object[4];

    list[0] = arg1;
    list[1] = arg2;
    list[2] = arg3;
    list[3] = arg4;

}

void printList() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.println(list[i]);
    }

}

@Override
public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    Iterator<T> iter = new list.iterator();
    return iter;
}
}
```

it doesnt work at the part

```
Iterator<T> iter = new list.iterator();
```

any ideas or thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Arrays do not provide an iterator per se, you will have to implement one. A simple solution in your case might be to take ``Arrays.asList(…).iterator()``.

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually reimplement the `Iterator` interface; there's no such thing as `list.iterator()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `list` is an array, and as such it has no member `iterator()` and less an inner class. `iterator` to make an instance of.

You could implement your [iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) index based where `hasNext()` returns `index < actIndex` and `next()` returns `list[itIndex]` and throws a `NoSuchElementException` if it was called after `hasNext()` returned false.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array is meant to be always entirely filled with elements, a minimal Iterator implementation could look like this:

```
@Override public Iterator<T> iterator()
{
    final T[] list = this.list;
    return new Iterator<T>()
    {
        int idx;
        public boolean hasNext() { return idx < list.length; }
        public T       next()    { return list[ idx++ ]; }
        public void    remove()  { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    };
}
```

By the way, you should consider to declare the `list` member as private. Accessing it directly from places with knowledge about a narrower definition for type T (i.e. specialzed subclasses) could lead to ClassCastExceptions at runtime even though the code would compile fine with just a warning for the `(T[])` cast you get in the contructor.